# Как выбрать из массива одинаковые числа и посчитать их?

Tags: массивы, циклы, выборка

Смысл игры - 20 раундов; выпасть может одно из 3 значений (случайно); в итоге мне надо узнать сколько раз выпала комбинация из максимального количества нулей, т. е. например, тут:

```
1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,2,0,0,2,1
```

Результат должен быть соответственно - 4, т. к. это максимальное количество выпавших подряд нулей.

Подскажите, пожалуйста,как сделать это?

```
var stavka = []; //Может быть 0, 1, 2 как ниже в переменных
var red = 0;
var black = 1;
var zero = 2;
alert(stavka);
var raunds = 20; //количество бросков 
var i = 0; // счетчик

for(i=0; i<raunds; i++) {
    stavka.push(Math.round(Math.random()*2)); //происходит случайный выбор числа (0, 1, 2) в 20 бросков 
}
var rezultat=(stavka); //Записываю массив в переменную

for (i=0; i<rezultat.length; i++) { //Получаю кол-во сколько раз выпало Красное (var red = 0;)
    if (rezultat[i] == 0 ) {
        red++;
    }
}

for(find in rezultat){ //Получаю индексы всех значений выпавших Красное (var red = 0;)
  if(rezultat[find]=="0") {
    var index=(rezultat);
    alert(find)
  }
 } 
alert("Количество выпадения red" + red);

//Как связать поиск нулей, их индексов и получить результат в виде количества нулей в максимальной последовательности?
```

Comment: Это так и задумано, чтобы значение "1" выпадало в два раза чаще, чем "0" и "2"?

Answer (score 1):

пример для 2х значений - красное и белое:

```js
// красное - черное - зеро вероятность выпадения
 var arr = [];
 var rounds = 100;
 var n = 0;
 var i = 0;
 var max_length = 0;
 var length = 0;

 for (i = 0; i <= rounds; i++) {
  n = Math.round(Math.random() * 36);
  if ( n != 0) {
   n = (n % 2) * 2 - 1;
  }
  arr.push(n);
 }
 console.log(arr);

 for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == 1) {
   length = 0;
   while (i < arr.length && arr[i] == 1) {
    i++;
    length++;
   }
   if (length > max_length) {
    max_length = length;
   }
  }
 }

 console.log('Максимально длинная красная последовательность: ' + max_length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let s = '112220000011100',
    r = {};

s.replace(/(\d)\1*/g, _ => r[_[0]] = Math.max(r[_[0]] || 0, _.length));

console.info(r['0']); // 5
```

Comment: что здесь за магия происходит? объясни пожалуйста: s.replace(/(\d)\1*/g, _ => r[_[0]] = Math.max(r[_[0]] || 0, _.length));

Comment: @stas0k, ищем любые максимальные последовательности одинаковы цифр и добавляем по ключу-цифре максимальную длину - либо то, что есть, либо новую (если она длиннее). На выходе получаем объект с ключами из присутствующих цифр (уникальных) и значением длины максимальной последовательности этой цифры.

Comment: как ты научился этому? Ведь совсем не очевидно что здесь мы ищем максимальную последовательность  s.replace(/(\d)\1*/g, _ . Знак подчёркивание ещё.

Comment: @stas0k, обучение и опыт, друг мой :) Регулярное выражение говорит: возьми цифру и, возможно, её максимальное повторение. Подчёркивание - это просто переменная.